# Subtract two splines in Sage

Tags: interpolation, ode, sage

I've got the following working Sage code.

P and P2 are a result of two calls to desolve_system (which happens to be a set of two first-order differential equations, so it is a list of three columns), and then I define the two lists

```
Q=[[i,k] for i,j,k in P]
Q2=[[i,k] for i,j,k in P2]
```

which grabs the first and last column in P and P2. Then I interpolate between the points of the two lists:

```
intP=spline(Q)
intP2=spline(Q2)
```

I can then plot these things on the same plot:

```
plot(intP,0,15)+plot(intP2,0,15)
```

This is all fine, plot looks perfect. Now I want to plot the absolute value of the difference of the two splines. I've tried things like

```
plot(abs(intP-intP2),0,15)
```

but I get errors about "-" not being a valid command for splines. So can someone give me one of the two following things:

1) A way to subtract splines

2) A way to subtract those two lists, so I can get another list I can then apply a spline to. Something like

```
Q3=[[i,Q[j]-Q2[j]] for i,j in Q,Q2]
```

(which doesn't work, since I'm referencing both list indices and values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Subtracting splines

Indeed, you can't subtract spline objects. But you can define a function that will return the difference of their values, and plot that function. It's easiest to define it as a lambda function right as you're plotting it:

```
plot(lambda x: intP(x)-intP2(x), 0, 15)
```

(or `plot(lambda x: abs(intP(x)-intP2(x)), 0, 15)` if you want the absolute value).

If you need this difference in multiple places, define it as a named function:

```
def spline_difference(x):
    return intP(x)-intP2(x)
```

#### Subtracting datapoints for splines

I think this is only practical when the interpolation nodes (the values of independent variable) are the same for both arrays. If you are solving the ODE systems using `desolve_system_rk4` on the same interval with the same step size, then they are. In this case, you can obtain the difference values with `map` method:

```
Qdiff = map(lambda x,y: (x[0], x[1]-y[1]), P, P2)
```

This processes the lists P and P2, taking the independent variable from P as well as the difference of the y-values. Then you can build `spline(Qdiff)` and plot it. (Remark: I used a tuple instead of a list to hold a pair of coordinates, which is more semantic, though `spline` accepts either thing.)

If the two lists P and P2 have different values of independent variable, then you'd need to interpolate in order to subtract and then interpolate again, which seems suboptimal. In this case I'd just go with "subtracting splines" approach.